# Atualizar o banco de dados corretamente

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, tabela-html

**Atualizado**: [Link](https://youtu.be/7ORrOvpDZmY) com um video que exemplifica melhor a situação.

---

Tenho um grande problema, estou com dificuldades para atualizar o banco de dados e exibir os dados atualizados em 2 `DataTables` diferentes.

Tenho duas páginas, uma só é visível para funcionário de cargo `Liberacao` e a outra pro cargo `Auditor`

**Pagina da Liberacao:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pagina do Auditor**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um botão pega o objeto selecionado em cada linha. Ele abre um `Dialog` que é carregado pelo `Bean`. Nessa pagina que aberta tenho o botão de `Enviar auditoria` e `Concluir Auditoria` Quando eu Envio a Auditoria ela é editada no banco de dados com o `cargo` de quem a enviou e o `status` aguardando.

Na pagina Liberação na tabela `Auditorias Recebidas` é listado apenas o que foi enviado pelo `Auditor` e estiver com o status `Aguardando`. E na pagina do Auditor em "Auditorias Recebidas só é listado o que foi enviado pela `Liberação` e o status for `Aguardando`.

O problema é o seguinte, quando acabo de realizar uma operação de envio e volto para a tabela mesmo após apertar f5 diversas vezes a tabela não atualiza todas as vezes, as vezes ela atualiza e as vezes não. Gostaria de ajuda para poder fazer a atualização do banco corretamente:

Aqui está meu método que faz a pesquisa e preenche minha Lista na tela do Auditor:

```
ManagedBean(name = "controleAuditoriaBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ControleAuditoriaAuditorBean {
private List<SolicitacoesBD> list;
private List<SolicitacoesBD> listEnviados;
@PostConstruct
    public void carregarPesquisa() {

        try {
            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            //Se o cargo for "Liberacao" e o Status for "Aguardando" faz a pesquisa.
            list = solicitacaoDAO.listarPorUsuario("Liberacao", "Aguardando");


            System.out.println("Caminho: "+solicitacoesBD.getCaminhoArquivo());
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

}
E aqui está o da tela da Liberacao:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "controleAuditoriaLibBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ControleAuditoriaLiberacaoBean {
    private List<SolicitacoesBD> list;
    private List<SolicitacoesBD> listFiltrada;
    @PostConstruct
    public void carregarPesquisa(){
        try{
            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            list = solicitacaoDAO.listarPorUsuario("Auditor", "Aguardando");
            carregarEnviados();
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao tentar listar as Auditorias");
        }
    }
}
```

Metodo que carrega listaEnviados do Auditor, o da liberação é semelhante:

```
// mostra na tabela de baixo todos os dados enviados
    public void carregarEnviados() {
        try {
            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            listEnviados = solicitacaoDAO.listarEnviados("Auditor");

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao tentar listar as Auditorias");
        }
    }
```

---

Atualizado

Fazendo alguns testes percebi que a lista não é carregada "imediatamente" com os dados do banco, demora em torno de 15 segundos até que a lista seja preenchida com os dados atuais, mesmo o `@postConstruct` e o `<f:event>` com `preRenderView` não atualiza a tabela de imediato. E mesmo assim ainda não consegui achar aonde está o problema.

Comment: Como está o código da página? Eu já tive um problema mt similar usando `RichFaces` que resolvia usando o `ReRender` corretamente

Comment: Como tu popula o `listEnviados`?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o método.

Comment: Fiz um teste e se eu espero uns 20 segundos após a ação e der um atualizar a dataTable atualiza corretamente, ou seja, a linha que foi enviada some, mas só após 20, 25 segundos

Comment: Editei a pergunta, tenho um método desse em cada bean, a unica diferença é nessa linha `listEnviados = solicitacaoDAO.listarEnviados("Auditor");` que muda pra `Liberacao` na tela de liberacao

Comment: Cara ja tive um problema com primefaces por causa do Cache do navegador. Tente dar uma limpada. E tente adicionar um process="@this" e update nos botões da tabela.

Comment: beleza, vou tentar

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: @Techies pode postar o xhtml? O você verificou e o valor esta corretamente persistido no banco logo após a confirmação certo?

Comment: Por que você não poe o ControleAuditoriaAuditorBean como RequestScope? Já debugou para ver se o carregarPesquisa do ControleAuditoriaAuditorBean é chamado ao enviar uma auditoria? Pode ser um simples problema de ajax / requisição.

Comment: Já tentei, porém o botão selecionar que fica dentro da minha dataTable não funcionava. A unica forma de resolver o problema que encontrei foi fazer a tabela de "Enviados" em outra tela. Agora está funcionado

Comment: Sei que não tem nada a ver mas,  qual nome desse template que você tá usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei várias coisas e nada deu certo, a única solução que encontrei e que funcionou foi tirar a `dataTable` de Auditorias Enviadas da mesma página que as recebidas e criei um `Bean` separado para gerenciar essas páginas. Eu não sei o porque mas funcionou.

**ATUALIZADO**
O problema foi resolvido com apenas um `commit` no método que faz a pesquisa, antes eu não comitava as consultas do banco.